# NPM RUN DEV in laravel 9

Tags: php, npm, xampp, laravel-artisan, laravel-9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76gpW.jpg)I have a problem when I create a new project in laravel and I want to build authintication ...this is my cmd command :

```
laravel new laravel2030
cd laravel2030
composer require laravel/ui 
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install 
npm run dev
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any issues with the commands you're running here. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: the screen stop here , and when I open my project the login and register page do not have this css style .

Comment: laravel mix not complete downloading .

Comment: Open up your browser's developer console and see if there are any errors there. Also double-check that the page is loading the css from the correct path.

Comment: I send an image  when I open developer console...please see it and give me response ...thanks alot .

Comment: Yes, it's trying to load the CSS/JS from the wrong path *or* the files don't exist. You don't show the code for that, or the location of the compiled files, so it's hard to tell

Comment: thank you very much  , I found that to paste this code in the projects and it work good ...<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
thanks for help.

Answer (score 7):

in laravel 9 update we use Vite instead of mix
then you need run command below instead npm run dev to build app.js, app.css:

**Running Vite Command to build Asset File**

```
npm run build
```

**see more about this in:https://techvblogs.com/blog/how-to-install-bootstrap-5-in-laravel-9-with-vite**

Comment: app.css causes error upon running the website `Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/sass/app.scss`

Comment: hi mate , you need to run this command `npm run build` to build app.css, app.js

Comment: where is location after make app.css and app.js

Comment: When I do npm run build, all the console log is being removed. How to develop with npm run build? npm run dev isn't working correctly, site doesn't load.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 9 this command works too.

```
vite build --watch
```

https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#rebuild-on-files-changes

Answer (score 1):

now laravel started to implement Vite instead of mixin

so you need to revert back to mix which I don't recommend

by intsalling laravel mix

```
npm i laravel-mix
```

then update the scripts section in package.json to be like this

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```

OR second option update your laravel ui view files to be compatible with vite which I think is a matter of time till laravel ui package make an update to implement this by default
You can follow this tutorial starting from step 5(if you already have a project) or follow from first step to create new project and see how you can fix this

https://techvblogs.com/blog/how-to-install-bootstrap-5-in-laravel-9-with-vite

you'll just need to edit in 4 files I think to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in package.json file

You have to change "dev": "vite" in package.json

```
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "mix build"
    }
```

to be "dev":"mix" like this

```
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "mix",
    "build": "mix build"
    }
```

and run npm run dev again.